# Dynamically create download links to file with php, mysql and vuejs

Tags: php, mysql, vue.js, download, vuejs2

Hey everyone so I'm having a bit of trouble I'm trying to dynamically create download links in php and pass them to my vuejs app. If the does not exist however I'm trying to set a file to an empty string. Any help here would be great.

```
<?php require_once('init.php');
$query="SELECT * FROM `bannerStock`";
$result = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
    $myArray=[];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $name=$row['name'];
         $categorytoadd="";
      if($row['Automotive']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Automotive';}
                                if($row['Backgrounds']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Backgrounds';}
                                if($row['Church']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Church';}
                                if($row['Community']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Community';}
                                if($row['Money']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Money';}
                                if($row['Food']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Food';}
                                if($row['Gaming']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Gaming';}
                                if($row['Healthcare']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Healthcare';}
                                if($row['Holidays']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Holidays';}
                                if($row['Sports']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Sports';}
                                if($row['Patriotic']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Patriotic';}
                                if($row['Retail']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Retail';}
                                if($row['Education']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Education';}
                                if($row['Misc']==1){$categorytoadd.=' Misc';}
                                $rowNumb=$row['id'];
    $poster = "<video style='width:400px; height=200px;' controls loop preload=\"none\" poster=\"https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/" . $row['name'] ."/". $row['name'] ."_thumb.jpg\"><source src=\"https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/". $row['name'] ."/". $row['name'] ."_thumb.mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"><source src=\"https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/". $row['name'] ."/". $row['name'] ."_thumb.webm\" type=\"video/webm\">";
    $link1 =  'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_1080.mp4';
    $link2 =  'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_1080.wmv';
    $link3 =  'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_1080.jpg';

    $link4 = 'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_432.mp4';
    $link5 = 'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_432.wmv';
    $link6 = 'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_432.jpg';

    $link7 = 'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_324.mp4';
    $link8 = 'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_324.wmv';
    $link9 = 'https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_324.jpg';

    $link10 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_216.mp4';
    $link11 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_216.wmv';
    $link12 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_216.jpg';

    $link13 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_184.mp4';
    $link14 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_184.wmv';
    $link15 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_184.jpg';

    $link16 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_160.mp4';
    $link17 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_160.wmv';
    $link18 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_160.jpg';

    $link19 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_128.mp4';
    $link20 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_128.wmv';
    $link21 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_128.jpg';

    $link22 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_108.mp4';
    $link23 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_108.wmv';
    $link24 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_108.jpg';

    $link25 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_80.mp4';
    $link26 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_80.wmv';
    $link27 ='https://www.siteaddress.com/ce/bannerStockUpload/'.$name.'/'.$name.'_80.jpg';

    if(file_exists($link1)){
    $row['link1'] = $link1;
    } else {$row['link1']='';}

        if(file_exists($link2)){
    $row['link2'] = $link2;
    } else {$row['link2']='';}

        if(file_exists($link3)){
    $row['link3'] = $link3;
    } else {$row['link3']='';}

        if(file_exists($link4)){
    $row['link4'] = $link4;
    } else {$row['link4']='';}

        if(file_exists($link5)){
    $row['link5'] = $link5;
    } else {$row['link5']='';}

        if(file_exists($link6)){
    $row['link6'] = $link6;
    } else {$row['link6']='';}

        if(file_exists($link7)){
    $row['link7'] = $link7;
    } else {$row['link7']='';}

        if(file_exists($link8)){
    $row['link8'] = $link8;
    } else {$row['link8']='';}

        if(file_exists($link9)){
    $row['link9'] = $link9;
    } else {$row['link9']='';}

        if(file_exists($link10)){
    $row['link10'] = $link10;
    } else {$row['link10']='';}

        if(file_exists($link11)){
    $row['link11'] = $link11;
    } else {$row['link11']='';}

        if(file_exists($link12)){
    $row['link12'] = $link12;
    } else {$row['link12']='';}

        if(file_exists($link13)){
    $row['link13'] = $link13;
    } else {$row['link13']='';}

        if(file_exists($link14)){
    $row['link14'] = $link14;
    } else {$row['link14']='';}

        if(file_exists($link15)){
    $row['link15'] = $link15;
    } else {$row['link15']='';}

        if(file_exists($link16)){
    $row['link16'] = $link16;
    } else {$row['link16']='';}

        if(file_exists($link17)){
    $row['link17'] = $link17;
    } else {$row['link17']='';}

        if(file_exists($link18)){
    $row['link18'] = $link18;
    } else {$row['link18']='';}

        if(file_exists($link19)){
    $row['link19'] = $link19;
    } else {$row['link19']='';}

        if(file_exists($link20)){
    $row['link20'] = $link20;
    } else {$row['link20']='';}

        if(file_exists($link21)){
    $row['link21'] = $link21;
    } else {$row['link21']='';}

        if(file_exists($link22)){
    $row['link22'] = $link22;
    } else {$row['link22']='';}

        if(file_exists($link23)){
    $row['link23'] = $link23;
    } else {$row['link23']='';}

        if(file_exists($link24)){
    $row['link24'] = $link24;
    } else {$row['link24']='';}

        if(file_exists($link25)){
    $row['link25'] = $link25;
    } else {$row['link25']='';}

        if(file_exists($link26)){
    $row['link26'] = $link26;
    } else {$row['link26']='';}

        if(file_exists($link27)){
    $row['link27'] = $link27;
    } else {$row['link27']='';}

    $row['class']= $categorytoadd;
    $row['poster'] = $poster;
    array_push($myArray, $row);

}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
      <input type='text' v-model='keyword' placeholder='search item'>
  <button v-on:click='showall'>ALL</button>
      <button v-on:click="showauto">Auto</button>
      <button v-on:click="showbackgrounds">Backgrounds</button>
      <button v-on:click="showchurch">Church</button>
      <button v-on:click="showcommunity">Community</button>
      <button v-on:click="showmoney">Money</button>
      <button v-on:click="showfood">Food</button>
      <button v-on:click="showgaming">Gaming</button>
      <button v-on:click="showhealthcare">Healthcare</button>
      <button v-on:click="showholidays">Holidays</button>
      <button v-on:click="showsports">Sports</button>
      <button v-on:click="showpatriotic">Patriotic</button>
      <button v-on:click="showretail">Retail</button>
      <button v-on:click="showeducation">Education</button>
      <button v-on:click="showmisc">Misc</button>


      <div v-for="item in filteredItemList">
<div :class="['video', item.class]">
    <div v-html='item.poster'>

    </div>
    <p>{{ item.name_short }} - {{item.id}}</p>
    <select>
    <option v-if="link1!===''">
    <a :href="item.link1">1920x1080.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link2!===''">
    <a :href="item.link2">1920x1080.wmv</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link3!===''">
    <a :href="item.link3">1920x1080.jpg</a>    
        </option>

    <option v-if="link4!===''">
    <a :href="item.link4">432x432.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link5!===''">
    <a :href="item.link5">432x432.wmv</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link6!===''">
    <a :href="item.link6">432x432.jpg</a>    
    </option>

    <option v-if="link7!===''">
    <a :href="item.link7">432x324.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link8!===''">
    <a :href="item.link8">432x324.wmv</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link9!===''">
    <a :href="item.link9">432x324.jpg</a>

    <option v-if="link10!===''">
    <a :href="item.link10">432x216.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link11!===''">
    <a :href="item.link11">432x216.wmv</a>    
        </option>
        <option v-if="link12!===''">
    <a :href="item.link12">432x216.jpg</a>    
        </option>

    <option v-if="link13!===''">
    <a :href="item.link13">432x184.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link14!===''">
    <a :href="item.link14">432x184.wmv</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link15!===''">
    <a :href="item.link15">432x184.jpg</a>    
        </option>

    <option v-if="link16!===''">
    <a :href="item.link16">432x160.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link17!===''">
    <a :href="item.link17">432x160.wmv</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link18!===''">
    <a :href="item.link18">432x160.jpg</a>    
    </option>

    <option v-if="link19!===''">
    <a :href="item.link19">432x128.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link20!===''">
    <a :href="item.link20">432x128.wmv</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link21!===''">
    <a :href="item.link21">432x128.jpg</a>

    <option v-if="link22!===''">
    <a :href="item.link22">432x108.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link23!===''">
    <a :href="item.link23">432x108.wmv</a>    
        </option>
        <option v-if="link24!===''">
    <a :href="item.link24">432x108.jpg</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link25!===''">
    <a :href="item.link25">432x80.mp4</a>    
        </option>
    <option v-if="link26!===''">
    <a :href="item.link26">432x80.wmv</a>    
        </option>
        <option v-if="link27!===''">
    <a :href="item.link27">432x80.jpg</a>    
        </option>

    </select>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      itemList: [],
        keyword:'',
    },
    created: function() {
        this.loaddata();
    },
    methods: {
            loaddata: function(){
                  var vueapp = this;
                        vueapp.itemList = <?php echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;
                },
        showall: function(){
            $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
          $('.video:not(.all)').show();  
        },
        showauto: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Automotive)').hide();
        },

        showbackgrounds: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Backgrounds)').hide();            
        },

        showchurch: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Church)').hide();
        },

        showcommunity: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Community)').hide();
        },

        showmoney: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Money)').hide();
        },

        showfood: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Food)').hide();
        },

        showgaming: function(){
       $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
       $('.video:not(.all)').show();
       $('.video:not(.Gaming)').hide();
        },

        showhealthcare: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Healthcare)').hide();
        },

        showholidays: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Holidays)').hide();
        },

        showsports: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Sports)').hide();
        },

        showpatriotic: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Patriotic)').hide();
        },

        showretail: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Retail)').hide();
        },

        showeducation: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Education)').hide();
        },
        showmisc: function(){
        $('.video:not(.all)').hide();
        $('.video:not(.all)').show();
        $('.video:not(.Misc)').hide();
        },        
    },
        computed:{
    filteredItemList(){
      return this.itemList.filter((item) => {
        return item.name_short.toLowerCase().includes(this.keyword.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
  }
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I currently get an error like this: **- invalid expression: Unexpected token = in
    link11!===''
  Raw expression: v-if="link11!===''"**

I just need a way to create dynamic download links that can be passed into my vue app from php. If one of you geniuses can either show me whats wrong with my code or show me a better way I would appreciate it.

Comment: Overall, you should really get familiar with loops. I see you're already using at least one, so you're on the right path.

Comment: Geeze, read up on `v-for`, php arrays and json.. get rid of jquery you dont need it, you can use `v-show` instead..

Answer (score 1):

You have one `=` too much in those conditional expressions.

For example, in:

```
<option v-if="link11!===''">
```

Remove a `=`, like:

```
<option v-if="link11!==''">
```

--

Do:

```
data: {
  itemList: [],
  keyword:'',
  link1: '', // added from here
  link2: '',
  link3: '',
  link4: '',
  link5: '',
  link6: '',
  link7: '',
  link8: '',
  link9: '',
  link10: '',
  link11: '',
  link12: '',
  link13: '',
  link14: '',
  link15: '',
  link16: '',
  link17: '',
  link18: '',
  link19: '',
  link20: '',
  link21: '',
  link22: '',
  link23: '',
  link24: '',
  link25: '',
  link26: '',
  link27: '', // to here
},
```

I declared the props one by one to keep the pattern you already use. But, as comments mentioned, you should probably look into using a loop.

Comment: Now I'm getting output but I'm getting this error vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Property or method "link16" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Comment: that doesn't work. I need each json object to have link values that's why I'm doing all this up in the for loop.

Comment: yeah the error goes away but than nothing works. I need those values for each name because I'm checking to see if a file with the name of $row['name'] exists in each of them with different extentions.

Comment: That's because your `itemList: []` is an empty array. You have to populate it with the necessary data.

Comment: no no no item list works fine. I can search and search by category. The only part of the document that isn't working is the links and dynamic downloads.

Comment: You have to populate the links in `itemList`'s elements. I see each item of yours have `name_short` and `id` properties (`{{ item.name_short }} - {{item.id}}`). But I don't see where you set those. Basically, you would have to set `link1`...`link27` along `name_short` and `id` props of each `item`.

Comment: its all in my select all from bannerStock I populate the array with the output of the query  methods: {
            loaddata: function(){
                  var vueapp = this;
                        vueapp.itemList = <?php echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ?>;

Comment: Can you paste an example of that JSON?

Comment: Its not a json problem. I know this because it works.  it wont let me it says its too long

Comment: Did I say it is a JSON problem? I'm sorry. I need to see the structure of the JSON so I know what is missing or not. You don't have to paste it fully, just a item or two. You can paste it on http://gist.github.com

Comment: Just to confirm, is that the content of `$myArray`? I don't see any `linkXX` there, is it normal?

Comment: its most of the content of myArray I appended poster and the links after and class after the fact with php. both of which work. even the link variables show up in chromes vue inspecter. They are just empty.

Comment: Uhm, how are you setting the link variables? Can you, instead of using `item.linkXX = 'somelink';` do `Vue.set(item, 'linkXX', 'somelink');`?

Comment: I've never heard of that before I'll have to look that up.

Comment: Here's the source for that: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats